# How is one NURBS surface rendered?

Tags: opengl, rendering, cad, nurbs

I know that GPU is efficient for rendering triangles. GPU can't render NURBS surface directly.  From the link [NURBS in the OpenGL Graphics Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907454/nurbs-in-the-opengl-graphics-pipeline),  we know that. To render NURBS, triangulation is required. I don't know where  triangulation operation occurs. Is it performed by CAD modeling software or GPU? I guess this is done by CAD modeling software.  So the triangulation functionality of NURBS surface is one core task for any CAD modeling software?  Is this task very complex or is solved almost completely by academic researchers?

Why do I have this question? I find that NURBS surfaces are smooth in CAD modeling software? However  if I convert the NURBS surface to triangle mesh first and open it by MeshLab. In MeshLab, some  regions are not smooth. I hope to know which part in the pipeline causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible reasons for seeing different rendering images between the CAD Modeling software you used and MeshLab:

- When the CAD software renders the NURBS surface, the resolution of the triangle mesh it generates internally typically will be dependent on the zoom level. When you used a different software (or even a command in the same CAD software) to convert the NURBS surface to a triangle mesh, there is no guarantee that you are getting the same triangle mesh.
- When CAD software renders a NURBS surface, not only it generates a triangle mesh, the surface normal at each triangle vertex is also computed from the NURBS surface and passed to the rendering engine. When MeshLab renders the triangle mesh which probably will not contain any vertex normal data, it will have to compute the vertex normal data by its own algorithm (typically inferred from all the triangles sharing the same vertex). So, different vertex normal data will lead to different rendered images.
- The CAD software you used and MeshLab could use totally different shading techniques.

All in all, these are just some possible reasons. If you can provide actual images, it will be helpful in further narrowing down the real cause.

Answer (score 0):

Typically it's done on the CPU, by the CAD software.  If you could post screen shots of the difference you're seeing, it would be easier to diagnose the cause of the problem.  It might just be using face normals or something.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure whether triangulation of NURBS curves and surfaces is one difficult task. I always work with triangle meshes from 3D scanners. Whatever tools you use to obtain one 3D model, do the user have to convert models into triangle meshes for practical applications finally?

Comment: NURBS curves and surfaces are converted into a form that graphics cards expect for display, namely polylines and triangle meshes.  This triangulation can be complex in certain cases (for example, with trimming curves/booleans), but in many cases it's pretty straightforward.  Images of what you see in CAD and what you see in MeshLab would be helpful to diagnose the problem.